# Rendering Issue of Safari Radio Buttons

Tags: html, css, safari, radio-button

I am experiencing a weird problem on radio buttons for safari here is my code below:

HTML

```
            <form>
                <input id="rbTextView" type="radio" name="projectView" class="nsRadioButtons" />Text View
                <input id="rbThumbnailView" type="radio" name="projectView" class="nsRadioButtons" checked="checked" />Thumbnail View
            </form>
```

CSS

```
 .nsRadioButtons
 {
     vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

This piece of code renders like these on safari

[image]

Here are the output for other browsers

[image]

Comment: That's weird, did you try reproducing the issue in any fiddle at all? Which version of Safari?

Comment: Hi @Kicker ! I'm using safari 5.1.7 for windows 7 64bit. I havent tried to use fiddle yet. :)

Comment: @Kicker I've forgot to mention, I had switched my desktop appearance to classic from windows 7. then this occurred.